# wso2 ESB request is truncated

Tags: soap, wso2, wso2-esb

i'm using fresh installation of wso2 esb 4.8.1 with stanalone default configuration.
when i send soap request to my backend (perl service with soap lite), the body of POST request is truncated like this according to tcpdump:

```
SOAPAction:      ""
Content-Type:    text/xml
Content-Length:  511
Host:            192.168.11.234:8181
Connection:      Keep-Alive
User-Agent:      Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="htt
p://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soap:Body>
    <deleteAccountForHost xmlns="AbcdeHostingPhysicalHostManagerCPanelService">
   <host xsi:type="xsd:string">zs000.abcde.net</host>
   <user xsi:type="xsd:string">tstauto</user>
</deleteAccountForHost>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envel
```

You can see that closing tag `'</soap:Envel'` is truncated.

But when i enable SOAP-tracer the request body becomes valid.
i use PT transport. I tried to switch transport to the nhttp and this problem seems to be disappeared.

So the question is: how to configure PT transport to avoid such strange behavior?

**UPD1:**
it seems that the problem occurs only when set the property FORCE_HTTP_1.0 and transport is PT

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, but I set DISABLE_CHUNKING.

After many tries I tested that disabling chunking or forcing HTTP 1.0 results in truncated request.

I use WSO2 ESB version 4.8.1, client is SoapUI 5.0.0 or SoapClient from PHP 5.5.11.

When I use "Try this service" in ESB, then request is not truncated.

After switching from HTTP PassThrough Transport to HTTP-NIO Transport service behind endpoint receives complete request, but then I can't download WSDL of tenant.